How do I get the terminal to stop telling me I have the wrong node.js version?
Every time I open the terminal, I am forced to see the message below.
Node.js version v18.1.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum of v18.13.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.


My current installed versions

node.js is v20.12.1
CLI is v17.3.7
npm is 10.7.0

I have tried uninstalling node.js, cli, and reinstalling. Same thing happens, and I think it may be something not related to the actual installation.

Most likely there is another version of node in your path.
You can find from where it comes from using the following commands on any Unix shell : which node
Or on Windows with PowerShell : get-command node
Find from where it comes from, uninstall it and put the Node 20.12.1 in your system or user path.
Alternatively i can recommand nvm (node version manager) which is a handy tool for managing a nodejs developpement environement :
Nvm for Unix environment
Nvm for Windows environment

using which node returns v20.12.1 also. I also use nvm and the only installed version is 20.12.1.

You can try to search your system for any rogue node.exe files, if you're on linux I can recommand you everything which can very rapidly locale any file on your computer, such as a node executable.
